# Is there SOAP web-services API in Project Server 2019?

Tags: project-server

We are planning to upgrade our Microsoft Project Sever 2007 to 2019 version. We use SOAP web-services to integrate with Microsoft Project Sever 2007. Our system administrators claim that 2019 version does not have SOAP API and propose to use REST API instead. Can you please confirm or refute if Microsoft Project Sever 2019 depricated SOAP API?

For integrating with Microsoft Project Sever 2007 I used SOAP request examples from https://pwa.company.com/PWA/_vti_bin/psi/project.asmx resource. But on new 2019 Project Server this link does not work.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation doesn't mention anything about web-services removal from Project Server, [other than the removal of OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/project/deprecated-removed-features-project-server-subscription-edition).

Answer (score 0):

The PSI services were deprecated on Project Server 2016. Here link to the documentation: [Project Server Interface (PSI) Project class removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/project/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-in-project-server-2016#project-server-interface-psi-project-class-removed)

> The Project class in the PSI is not supported in Project Servers 2016.
> For all new development, use the [Project Client Side Object Model (CSOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-class/jj236068(v=office.15)).